# Is there a way to access Android Storage Access Framwork (SAF) from Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, storage-access-framework

I am trying to write a notepad app using Flutter, which will save all the notes in a user selected folder.
So that it can be synced using something like Syncthing.
It seems that since Android 10, this is not possible using the normal File API in Dart.
Is there any way to access the new SAF API from Dart?

Comment: If you let the user select a folder then you get a SAF uri. And you got that already since Android Kitkat i believe. So you had to use SAF already a long time.

Comment: Further: with a minor tag attribute in manifest file you can let your app on an Android 10 device behave as before.

Comment: @blackapps yeah. I saw that it was there for a while. I am a newbie in app development. I started with flutter a few weeks ago. I was searching for a way to properly write a file in SD Card. Just came across the SAF API, but couldn't figure out how to use it from Flutter.

Comment: @blackapps I think I will do with the manifest tag for now. 
But I was wondering if there was any way to do it the proper way because requestLegacyExternalStorage will stop having an effect in Android 11.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But on Android 11 the restrictions are less again and you can easily create your own subdirectories in public directories like Documents, Download, Pictures, DCIM, Alarms and so on using classic File tools. And i do not program with Flutter so your SAF question stays.

Comment: can someone suggest dependency to get SAF uri in flutter?

Comment: @Sparks Did you find any relevant SAF dependency ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the change in Security policy for Android 9 or above. It is recommended to use the Storage Access Framework (SAF) API option to get access to storage (basic).

You can simply achieve that task using the flutter package called **saf**. You can search in the www.**pub.dev** package directory.

It basically gives you all the storage access framework API native implementation to the dart side. It opens the native OS file explorer then the user can grant permission of any particular directory and get access to perform some operations on it.

Comment: Here is the package link: [saf](https://pub.dev/packages/saf)

Comment: Was looking for this functionality like almost a month but no success, then finally it saved my life ! Thanks Again :)